# how to change from looking for am/pm to looking for seconds

Tags: c#, regex

found this datetime regular expression in RegExLib site -> http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=361

```
    string pattern = @"(((((0[13578])|([13578])|(1[02]))[\-\/\s]?((0[1-9])|([1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[01])))|((([469])|(11))[\-\/\s]?((0[1-9])|([1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(30)))|((02|2)[\-\/\s]?((0[1-9])|([1-9])|([1-2][0-9]))))[\-\/\s]?\d{4})(\s(((0[1-9])|([1-9])|(1[0-2]))\:([0-5][0-9])((\s)|(\:([0-5][0-9])\s))([AM|PM|am|pm]{2,2})))?";
    var match = Regex.Match("test 123 11/30/2003 10:12:24 am", pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

the datetime format i'm looking for is m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss

the above looks for m/d/yyyy hh:mm am|pm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two minutes of work using [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com) gave me a solution of:

```
string pattern = @"(((((0[13578])|([13578])|(1[02]))[\-\/\s]?((0[1-9])|([1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[01])))|((([469])|(11))[\-\/\s]?((0[1-9])|([1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(30)))|((02|2)[\-\/\s]?((0[1-9])|([1-9])|([1-2][0-9]))))[\-\/\s]?\d{4})(\s(((0[1-9])|([1-9])|([0-2][0-3]))\:([0-5][0-9])((\s)|(\:([0-5][0-9])))))";
```

This matches `11/30/2003 10:12:24` in your test expression. It also matches `11/30/2003 23:12:24` and `11/30/2003 00:00:01`

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking it should be something like the following.

```
(0?[1-9]|1[012])        // month
[\s\/-]                 // delimiter - space, fwd. slash or dash
(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])  // day
[\s\/-]                 // delimiter - space, fwd. slash or dash
\d{4}                   // year
\s                      // delimiter - space
(0?\d|1\d|2[0-3])       // hours
\:                      // delimiter - colon
(0?\d|[1-5]\d)          // minutes
\:                      // delimiter - colon
(0?\d|[1-5]\d)          // seconds
```

Remove the question marks next to zeros if you don't want to allow numbers like 0,1,2 etc. for single digits so that it will require a preceding zero for those. Also you should verify the date in the next step to make sure it exists. 31.02.2012 shouldn't pass, for example. And you might want an ending rule such as a positive lookahead for a space, punc. mark, end of word etc to avoid the seconds from validating when it's **:90** or **:231**.

Anyway I'm not using c# so I'm not sure how to wrap this right but I hope that helps.

**EDIT 1:** Shortened the regex - all occurance of `[0-9]` became `\d`
**EDIT 2:** And here's the version that requires preceding zeros for single digits:

```
(0[1-9]|1[012])        // month
[\s\/-]                // delimiter - space, fwd. slash or dash
(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])  // day
[\s\/-]                // delimiter - space, fwd. slash or dash
\d{4}                  // year
\s                     // delimiter - space
([01]\d|2[0-3])        // hours
\:                     // delimiter - colon
[0-5]\d                // minutes
\:                     // delimiter - colon
[0-5]\d                // seconds
```